# in the way in which many Republicans hoped?

Tags: usage

I encounter a sentence in an Economist article.

> It was, though not in the way that many Republicans hoped.

What I want to ask is whether I can use ***in which*** in place of ***that*** in the sentence? If ***that*** is used as relative adverb, I think ***in which*** can be used. But when I googled, ***the way in which somebody hoped*** had no results. Or, is ***that*** used as relative pronoun? ***hoped*** is an intransitive verb in the sentence, so it can't be used that way, can it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have correctly surmised that 'that' is a relative adverb, and 'in which' could be substituted. The following is correct and conveys the same idea as the original sentence:

> It was, though not in the way in which many Republicans hoped.

The double use of 'in' might be a little awkward, but your readers would definitely understand the meaning.